# Confused about definition for pte_t and __pte(x)

Tags: c

```
typedef struct { unsigned long pte; } pte_t;

#define __pte(x)        ((pte_t) { (x) } )
```

Why not use 'typedef unsigned long pte_t' directly?

Why '{ }' is used here?  It looks weird.

I know without those the gcc will report an error. However, how it works?

Comment: The braces are syntactically required since `pte_t` is a `struct` type, you can't initialize the member any other way (`pte_t x = 3;` is invalid, it has to be `pte_t x = { 3 };`).

Comment: Well, i am familiar with 'pte_t x = (pte_t) { 3 }. I just can't link this with that one. thx anyway

Comment: It's probably intended as a C99/GNU struct literal, so you can use it in non-initializer places. Then the cast is necessary (i.e. `pte_t x; x = __pte(4711);` won't work without them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the library, but I would bet that the intention is to prevent the automatic conversion between `pte_t` and integral types.

I mean, a `typedef` is just an alias for a type, so:

```
typedef unsigned long pte_t;

pte_t x = 3; //ok
char y = x; //ok
```

But a struct is a new type, so:

```
typedef struct { unsigned long pte; } pte_t;

pte_t x = 3; //error!
char y = x; //error!
```

Then provide a few functions, macros or whatever to get/set the `pte_t` internal field, and done.

UPDATE: Ok, I've found it. The *library* is the Linux kernel, and just next to it there is:

```
#define pte_val(x)      ((x).pte)
```

to access the value.

But looking a bit over it, under conditionally compiled code, there is this alternative definition:

```
typedef struct { unsigned long pte_low, pte_high; } pte_t;
#define pte_val(x)    ((x).pte_low | ((unsigned long long)(x).pte_high << 32))
```

See? Depending on the configuration, there may be just one field or several of them. It would be crazy to change from a single type to a struct. So it is defined always as a struct.